# How To Convert "Byted" String Back to Byte Without String

Tags: c#

I have an encryption key that looks like this:

> Z2FzYWdlYmk=

I read the key to a `byte[]` using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)`

My problem is when I try to turn the `byte[]` back into a string like this:  `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`

This doesn't help, because it need to be byte.

I just want to know how to "Remove" the string format on this key and then safety convert it back to a string again.

Comment: It is a base64 encoded string. Decode it, then you'll get the byte array.

Comment: You might consider using `Convert.FromBase64String` to get the `byte[]`, then run that through `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to get your final value.